# Twisted SSH multiple simultaneous commands

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, twisted

I've used twisted to make an SSH server similar to the one shown [here](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/SSH-with-Twisted/). My question is, is it possible to use multithreading to run multiple commands simultaneously? I tried making a do_ function that started a thread and that didn't accomplish what I was after. Should I make multiple client connections instead?

Comment: I actually just tried multiple client connections and they still could not run commands simultaneously.

Comment: You can multiplex several channels over a single SSH connection. I think that sounds like what you want.

Comment: Please read <http://sscce.org/> and then provide a minimal example.  It's very difficult to talk about your problem without actually knowing what it is.

Comment: Perhaps it's hard to see. The "here" in my question is a hyperlink to an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should look at adding Twisted sub process spawning support to your code?

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html

... it's a bit hard to be more specific as you haven't included any code for us to comment on.

Comment: I actually linked some code that mine is based off of if it would help you be more specific.

Comment: Turns out that doc you posted was all I needed. Thanks.